# Is this site the meta site for all of the Stack Exchange network, as well as the meta site for Stack Overflow proper?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, meta

I haven't seen it expressly stated anywhere but as I've spread my presence around more and more of Stack Exchange it's started to seem to me that there are not separate Meta sites for Stack Overflow specifically and the whole of Stack Exchange generally.

So have I assumed correctly that both general and SO-specific questions belong right here on `meta.stackoverflow.com`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, that's correct.**

meta.stackoverflow.com is both the site-specific meta for Stack Overflow, as well as the general meta site for discussing all things Stack Exchange.

As the blog post [announcing per-site metas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/) puts it:

> Meta Stack Overflow will serve as the “National Capital” where we process feedback not just for Stack Overflow but for the core engine itself — while the smaller meta sites are akin to regional or state capitals.

There used to be a separate site at `meta.stackexchange.com`, but that address now redirects here.

Comment: At least now anybody else wondering the same thing might stumble across this page via Google (-:

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes it difficult for Stack Overflow users to find questions that are specifically relevant to Stack Overflow.