# A Meta for StackOverflow only?

Tags: discussion, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this site the meta site for all of the Stack Exchange network, as well as the meta site for Stack Overflow proper?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92177/is-this-site-the-meta-site-for-all-of-the-stack-exchange-network-as-well-as-the)

In other posts, people say this is the meta for discussing (the platform of) **all** Stack Exchange sites.

So, **is there a Meta for StackOverflow *only*?** (like in all the other sites)
**Is it correct to ask questions here regarding StackOverflow only?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no meta site that is exclusively for Stack Overflow.
Yes, it is correct to ask questions regarding Stack Overflow here.

[This could clear it up.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/is-meta-just-for-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 3):

Currently meta.stackoverflow is supposed to be both the meta for stackoverflow.com and the meta.meta for all of stack exchange (or at least for the 'big 3').

Perhaps there *should* be a separation. The feeling with a lot of people from the 'other' sites that I've spoke to is that when an issue is posted here then if it isn't an issue for SO then its quickly sidelined and treated as if it isn't a problem at all. And I might imagine that some of the people who are only interested in SO don't find it helpful when 'their' meta is crowded with irrelevant stuff about other sites that makes finding SO specific discussion more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there should be meta.stackexchange.com too?

Comment: There was one but it was closed and the link is now redirecting to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: why? :( 1234567

Comment: Because it's completely unnecessary. This one here is perfectly good.