# How can I see questions on Meta Stack Overflow that are relevant to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow

Meta Stack Overflow, despite its name, appears to be a site for discussion about the entire Stack Exchange network, not just Stack overflow. Is it possible to filter questions on this site so that the questions displayed are relevant to Stack Overflow only, as opposed to the entire Stack Exchange network?

Also, are there plans to give the Stack Exchange network its own meta site, so that those types of questions can be separated from Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Wow, there's already a duplicate of this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93084/a-meta-for-stackoverflow-only?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

You can always follow the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag. We generally try to keep anything *specific* to Stack Overflow under that tag, but of course there are always the questions which sneak by. That's about the closest thing you'll get, though.

Also, they do have plans for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange), but who knows when that'll actually happen. ;)

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks, duh!

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you explain what you're referring to?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514